# if conditions not working in JS

Tags: conditionals, javascript

Why are my if conditions not working when they are inside a javascript but they work in plain html?
 the {if longitude} outputs {if""} when viewed in the browser.

```
{exp:user:users sort="asc" limit="100" group_id="5"}
{if longitude}
         {
            "properties": {                         
                "tags": [],
                "phone": "",
                "classifiers": ['a'],
                "address": "",
                "name": "{billing_name}",
                "province": "{billing_region}",
                "owner": "",
                "postcode": "",
                "city": "{billing_city}",
                "country": "{billing_country}"
            },
            "type": "Place",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ {longitude},{latitude} ]
            }
        },
{/if}
{/exp:user:users}
```

Comment: a solution seems to be using an embed instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default EE prevents the advanced conditional parser from processing anything between `<script>` tags. Try adding this config variable:

```
$config['protect_javascript'] = 'n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the case might be that the conditionals are being rendered by the js and not by EE. It wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

Strange anomaly, that I don't know if it still exists or not is that for this type of thing to work, I had to make sure that php error reporting was set to "1" for

```
jQuery(function(){
      options = {serviceUrl:'{site_url}utility/suggest_names'};
      a = $('#query').autocomplete(options);
    });
```

to work properly.

Comment: "$config['debug']= 0" and "$config['remove_unparsed_vars'] = 'y'"?